# Powershell send mail

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am having the following problem.
I have a powershell script to send me emails with log files attached.
The only problem is that I need only the log files that are not empty. 
So i have tried to use this script:

```
If ((Get-content "Log.txt") -gt 0 ) {
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    echo "email sent"
    } else {
    echo "File is blank"
    }
```

It seems that `-gt 0` is not working for me.
No matter what I have tried powershell still sends me the empty logs.
So can you please show me where I am wrong?
I have tried this as well:

```
If ((Get-Content $file) -eq $Null) {
    "File is blank"
    } else {
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    echo "email sent"
    }
```

But it is still not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about PowerShell, I basically avoid Windows altogether. But I would assume you could check the actual filesize instead of using `Get-content`. Then use filesize to determine whether or not to send the file.

Comment: Hi Josiah, thanks for the comment. I have tried with actual filesize but the result was the same . Empty file name is sent.

If ((Get-ChildItem "Log.txt") | foreach -process ( $_.length/1MB -gt ("0.00") )) {
    $smtp.Send($msg)
 echo "email sent"
 } else {
 echo "File is blank"
 }

The thing is that if i create a empty file its size is 0KB, but the log file on the server is 1KB even it is empty.

Comment: First of all I know you're new, just thought I'd let you know to wrap your code in backticks to format it in blocks. Secondly what I would do is see how big the file is if you just put one character in it. If it changes to 2KB then just consider anything <= 1KB as blank.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` will read the entire contents of the file - only to throw it all away! That's a huge waste of resources.

Instead, get info from the fileystem itself about the file with `get-item` or `get-childitem`.

```
if ((get-item "log.txt").length -gt 0) {
    do stuff
}
```

It also looks like you're using an antiquated method of sending email. In PowerShell 2.0 and above, use `Send-MailMessage` - it's much easier to use. In fact, if you have all the logfiles in one directory, you can distill this to a two-liner:

```
$logs = get-childitem -path PATH_TO_LOGS|where-object{($_.length -gt 0) -and !$_.PSIsContainer}|select-object -expandproperty fullname
Send-Mailmessage -attachments $logs OTHER_PARAMETERS_HERE
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
I have managed to do it using Send-Mailmessage and get-content  t check if file is empty or not.